# how to see past users' logcat without connecting their device to my Mac?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I'm developing a debug app. I give it to some beta users to try.

I saw I can download all kinds of apps ([a](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)) ([b](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector&feature=search_result)) that shows logcat on the device itself.

If i don't want the user to install additional app, how can they send me their log-cat file?

Connecting the device to eclipse DDMS allow me to see past logcat, but it usually show me only logcat that was written only after connecting to my Mac?

I have [read](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-logging/) it's a good practice to turn loggs off in production.

I thought to enable a hack: checking a editText field for a secret word that will turn the logger off and on again, so I'll still be able to see logs from production app.

How would the turn off/on code would look like?

Comment: The logcat shows you the log since the application starts

Comment: then how can i guid the beta users to send it to me without them connecting the device to a mac?

Comment: see that project: http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/

Comment: if they use catalog, they have to enable USB debugging (device shows developers' options)?

Comment: @JorgeB. - no, logcat shows whatever fraction of the log since android userspace startup has not been pushed out of the log buffer by more recent messages.  Often this can be a number of minutes even up to several hours, but if something is being very noisy it could be less.